# calculating burst time in operating system

Tags: process, operating-system, scheduling

how burst time calculated for process in os in real life scenario.say computer is having  5 processes to execute and is using shortest job first algorithm.then how OS will know in advance the burst time of each process??

Answer (score 0):

Since an operation system can not guess the burst time of a process *a priori*, usually one of the two following approaches is used:

- The process is annoted by the developer (e.g., by using methods of critical execution path analysis)
- The OS uses the execution time of a former process instance of the very same code the do an  estimation.

However, in "real life", SJF is rarely used, at least not as pure algorithm. It is more of theoretical interest.